# Identify cells with characters other than numbers in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have dataframe with two columns named A and B. How can I fill column B so that a cell will display "text" if A contains something other than a number or the number itself comma separated, and "number" when it is just a number?
(See the example below)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using `apply` on column `A` :

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'A': '4 tons'},
 {'A': '2.0*'},
 {'A': 4.1},
 {'A': 4.2},
 {'A': '4,2'},
 {'A': '6,3'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def checkType(x):
    try:
        #Trying to convert the value into a float type
        float(x)
        return 'number'
    except:
        #If there's an error, it's a text
        return 'text'
    
df['B'] = df.A.apply(lambda x : checkType(x))
```

**Output**

```
| A      | B      |
|:-------|:-------|
| 4 tons | text   |
| 2.0*   | text   |
| 4.1    | number |
| 4.2    | number |
| 4,2    | text   |
| 6,3    | text   |
```

Comment: Unfortunately the entire column is initially 'str'

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
import pandas as pd
# making just column A
ls = ['4 tons', '4.0*', '4,0', '4.1', '5.2', '6,3']
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = ls

df['B'] = ls  # copying for now

df["C"] = df["A"].str.replace(".", "")  # creating a pivot column
df["C"] = df['C'].str.isdigit()

i = 0
for elem in df['C']:
    if elem:
        df['B'][i] = 'number'
    else:
        df['B'][i] = 'text'

    i = i+1

del df['C']  # delete pivot column
```